# Using curl to use the build in Facebook like

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

Im trying to create the build in like button from facebook, but now facebook requieres to use the curl system, and onces i created the action, facebook gives me this code:

```
curl -F 'access_token=AAAAAKcSOZB8IBACXBZBQ1F5fUqqEeueY0bkj7eAZAeAWgjU5vU8c8ZC5X8L1ZAWGYVTlR0vySQQU0raZCuNCmPlcjxavrG6hsZD' \
 -F 'object=http://samples.ogp.me/226075010839791' \
    'https://graph.facebook.com/me/og.likes'
```

But I not sure how to invoque this code using a link or a form button, my site has several user access token store in a mysql

Onces the like command is send, facebook will send back a id_from_create_call which will have to be store so when a user dislikes something, the value send by facebook must be use here:

```
curl -X DELETE \
 -F 'access_token=AAAAAKcSOZB8IBACXBZBQ1F5fUqqEeueY0bkj7eAZAeAWgjU5vU8c8ZC5X8L1ZAWGYVTlR0vySQQU0raZCuNCmPlcjxavrG6hsZD' \
    'https://graph.facebook.com/{'{id_from_create_call}'}'
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

It will be better for you to use FB api..

Comment: Yes.  And you can skip the direct usage of Curl, since the SDK does it for you.